# WP can't easily select pages to add to navigation menu

Tags: wordpress

my problem is adding pages in wordpress navigation menus because there are many pages in my site and the pages meta box (in appearence -> menus) is not well indented. So, I can't find easily the right page in the list.
There is a way for reorder the page list hierarchically?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the search? It's useful and easy!

Comment: you're right but I have some pages with same name. for example:
people -> john doe, friends -> john doe. So if I search for "john doe" I can't easily find the right page.

Answer (score 1):

first get your pages address in pages worpress bar 
then go to appearence>menu  and  there you can add cusstom links to anything like your pages

Comment: but I need to link pages not custom links.

Comment: what is the diffrence

Comment: your page have a link

Comment: using custom links you loose the correspondence with original pages. for example: if you change the page slug the custom link doesen't change and you'll get a 404 error. the same if you change page hierarchy. I usually use custom links for external sites.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I used the Order field and Parent in Pages, you can sort and manage your pages in an order that will show in appearance -> Menus, you will see it as is in the following image.

[image]